# How to pass data between JFace wizard pages..?

Tags: java, swt, jface, wizard

Hi all i am working on JFace wizard in which i have multiple pages.
In one of my page i have a functionality where a user can select any number of folders from local machine and add them to SWT list on the same page.

```
   selectedFoldersList = new List(container, SWT.BORDER);
   selectedFoldersList.add(selectedFolderPath);
```

Now for performing the further action i want this list on the next page of wizard,
where the data from the list will be displayed into another List component,
How can i pass the data between pages on click of next button on a page..?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing data between JFace wizard pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15215740/passing-data-between-jface-wizard-pages)

Answer (score 0):

Wizard is a pattern to capture data step by step to perform an action. In your case, you need to populate the data that you gather in each page of wizard into a data model class and finally when you click finish you actually use this data to perform some action.

Comment: Thank you Sambi for replying..actually i was going to do the same as you have suggested on the click of finish button. But i got this condition which i have mentioned in my question, i have to pass the data between the pages at runtime, otherwise the wizard will be of no use to me. 
Thanks

Comment: I think sambi reddy meant to pass one and the same dataobject to all pages. and fill thised "shared" dataObject by the pages. when you finish alle data should be present in this dataObject.